# Strange problems with bot on Heroku

Tags: heroku, bots, telegram

my bot stationes on heroku behave strangely, since seems to work perfectly in private, but in group only works with new users and stopped working with me and other collaborators who used it often.

I ran a logs and got these errors. Anyone can help? Thank you!

> raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
> 2020-11-13T20:40:42.207588+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API
> was unsuccessful. Error code: 400 Description: Bad Request: have no
> rights to send a message 2020-11-13T20:40:42.207589+00:00
> app[worker.1]: " 2020-11-13T20:40:42.207869+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> 2020-11-13 20:40:42,207 (**init**.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot:
> "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400
> Description: Bad Request: have no rights to send a message"
>
> raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
> 2020-11-14T18:35:25.247259+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API
> was unsuccessful. Error code: 400 Description: Bad Request:
> CHAT_WRITE_FORBIDDEN 2020-11-14T18:35:25.247268+00:00 app[worker.1]: "
> 2020-11-14T18:35:25.247577+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2020-11-14
> 18:35:25,247 (**init**.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request
> to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400 Description: Bad
> Request: CHAT_WRITE_FORBIDDEN"

Answer (score 0):

Does the bot have Administrator rights in your group?
Seems like the bot is simply not allowed to send messages.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. And I repeat: it worked for days until yesterday, and actually STILL works with new users that enters groups where the bot is active. :\
Just me and few others can't use it anymore :\

Comment: well it seems like it has some restrictions regarding the chat. You should probably try looking at this more. Also just try removing and adding the bot again

Comment: tried that also ;___; 
In newly created group chats it works, just the old ones got problems...